# Member object of C++ class: Where should it be destroyed?

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-management, constructor

I have a little confusion about the following case. I have the following C++ class, representing a RGB pixel:

```
  class RgbColorVector
  {
       cv::Mat pM;

  public:
    RgbColorVector(unsigned int r,unsigned int g,unsigned int b)
    {
         pM = cv::Mat(3,1,CV_8UC1);
         pM.at<unsigned char>(0,0) = r;
         pM.at<unsigned char>(1,0) = g;
         pM.at<unsigned char>(2,0) = b;
}


unsigned int getComponent(int c)
{
    return (unsigned int)pM.at<unsigned char>(c,0);
}
```

Here I am using the OpenCV Mat object to hold a RGB value. Normally in such cases, I would use cv::Mat pointer and allocate heap memory in the constructor with new operator and then release it in the destructor with delete. In the case above, I explicitly call the constructor of cv::Mat. What I expected was that when the constructor of RgbColorVector exits, the allocated memory in the cv::Mat constructor would be destroyed. But apparently it is not the case:

```
 void func()
 {
     RgbColorVector rgbVec(105,42,45);
     int g = rgbVec.getComponent(1);
     std::cout<<g<<std::endl;
 }


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

Here, I get as the output 42. I am aware that "rgbVec" is a local(automatic) variable and when "func" exits, its contents (class members) will be destroyed. But moreover, I expected that the getComponent() call would return a random value, since any memory allocated in cv::Mat constructor call will be destroyed after the "rgbVec"s constructor return. I am a little bit confused here, how exactly the memory allocation mechanism works in that case? Isn't the cv::Mat object allocated on stack in the RgbColorVector() constructor?

Comment: I don't get what kind of behaviour you would expect. You are using the copy-constructor of a cv::Mat by pM = cv::Mat(3,1,CV_8UC1); so the constructed object is in your class member variable (where it will be destroyed if the class object is destroyed), which is at the end of func(). In addition, if you really would access deallocated memory, no "random" values are returned but the values that are there in the memory. If the memory still belongs to your program and wasn't overwritten you might even observe the "right" values if you accidentally deallocated the memory.

Comment: Very bad idea to use Mat to store a single pixel value. You'd better use Vec3b, or just use 3 uchars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class RgbColorVector
{
    cv::Mat pM; // <- this object is valid as long
                //    as the parent is (value semantics)

public:
    RgbColorVector(unsigned int r,unsigned int g,unsigned int b)
        // <- pM gets implicitly allocated here
    {
        pM = cv::Mat(3,1,CV_8UC1); // <- this creates a temporary, and
                                   //    assign its value to pM

        // <- the temporary gets implicitly deallocated here.
        //    pM isn't affected.

        pM.at<unsigned char>(0,0) = r;
        pM.at<unsigned char>(1,0) = g;
        pM.at<unsigned char>(2,0) = b;
    }
};
```

The proper way to initialize a member is like this:

```
    RgbColorVector(unsigned int r,unsigned int g,unsigned int b)
        : pM(3,1,CV_8UC1)
    {
```

This is called a member initializer list

Comment: When the temporary object is created with cv::Mat call it allocates memory in heap to hold color values. All the class members of temporary cv::Mat is copied into pM class members along with the data pointer, so this pixel data on the heap remains valid, is that right?

Comment: `cv::Mat` may or may not use the heap internally, that's up to that class, and should make no difference to the user. C++ uses value semantics, i.e. classes should behave like `int` does, If you copy a value, it does not matter what happen after to the original, the copy is unaffected.

Comment: @BattleBeast That's correct. It works similar to a shared pointer.

Comment: @sp2danny That's not entirely true in this case, it really does make sense to understand how `cv::Mat` works (as many questions on SO show). E.g. [assignment](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.10/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-operator): "Matrix assignment is an O(1) operation. This means that no data is copied but the data is shared and the reference counter, if any, is incremented."

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `cv::Mat` copy ctor, so the newly created temporary `cv::Mat` gets moved to already constructed `pM`. Thus, `pM` remains constructed and valid till the end of scope of the parent object. `pM` is never destructed, nor is any data held by `pM`.

However, OpenCV adds another dimension of indirection. `cv::Mat` stores data via a pointer to prevent duplication when not required, a form of shallow copy. It itself smartly manages data on the heap and removes the data when it is no longer being referred to by any other `cv::Mat`. So, even a `cv::Mat` object on the stack contains some data on the heap, and other details on the stack, which is the case with your `pM`. Not relevant, but since you are confused about the scope of `cv::Mat` and its data, I added some details.

Edit: temporary variable, move and default ctor thanks to [sp2danny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3202093/sp2danny)

Comment: it's not the copy constructor that get called, first the default constructor is implicitly called, then an explicit construction of a temporary get called, then move-assignment

Comment: ...which can be rectified by using an initializer list in the constructor for pM http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list